# Solve rectangular sparse linear equation systems with cupy

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, linear-algebra, chainer, cupy

I'm trying to solve a rectangular system for sparse features using cupy. I know the built-in function `sparse.linalg.lsqr(A, b)` do it for square matrix `A`. However I like to solve a rectangular sparse system. This is the way we can solve a squared system:

```
Import cupy as cp

A = cp.sparse.rand(200, 100, density=0.1)
b = cp.random.random(100)

x = cp.sparse.linalg.lsqr (A, b)
print(x)
```

It gives an error of dimension mismatch for rectangular systems and I can't find a built-in sparse method equivalent to e.g. `cupy.tensorsolve()`.

By the way, is there a way to do it with Tensorflow?
Thank you for help. I'm using google a Colaboratory notebook.

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late for questioner, but for posterity I answer this question.

This can be implemented by wrapping `lsqr` in [MAGMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/group__magmasparse__sgesv.html#ga2c10914e15d9fbb2bd7c30777c6d548a) as shown in [this example](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/tree/master/examples/gemm).

Answer (score -1):

You can refer https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/linalg.html for the current cupy's supporting functions for linear algebra. I can find `cupy.linalg.tensorsolve`, but I could not find `cupy.linalg.lsqr` so far.

Also I think it is nice to tag this question as "cupy" or "numpy".